# Goloka and Nirguna Braman

Tags: krishna, brahman, lokas

Beyond the multitude of Universes and Celestial Realms is Goloka the supreme abode of Krishna.  is it located before Nirguna Brahman or after Nirguna Brahman ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81090/discussion-on-question-by-frank-hestermann-goloka-and-nirguna-braman).

Answer (score 3):

A very good question. You want to know the relationship between Goloka and Nirguna Brahman. There is no relationship.

Goloka is the eternal loka or place for those who follow Bhakti Yoga and worship Brahman with form.

> Brahma said, ‘…The two regions of felicity, viz, Goloka and
>   Brahmaloka, became his upper and lower lips.’

*Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCXLVIII*

People who aim for Nirguna Brahman do not attain any loka. They just become Brahman.

There is no good explanation of the difference between the two either in scriptures or in the commentaries of ancient Acharyas. I am giving below the explanation that I find useful.

> No one can say with finality that God is only 'this' and nothing else.
>   He is formless and again He has forms. For the bhakta He assumes
>   forms. But He is formless for the jnani, that is, for him who looks on
>   the world as a mere dream. The bhakta feels that he is one entity and
>   the world as another. Therefore God reveals Himself to him as a
>   Person. But the jnani – the Vedantist, for instance - always reasons,
>   applying the process of 'Not this, not this'. Through this
>   discrimination he realizes, by his inner perception, that the ego and
>   the universe are both illusory, like a dream. Then the jnani realizes
>   Brahman in his own consciousness. He can not describe what Brahman is.
>
> Do you know what I mean? **Think of Brahman, Existence-Knowledge-Bliss
>   Absolute, as a shoreless ocean. Through the cooling influence as it
>   were, of the bhakta's love, the water has frozen at places into blocks
>   of ice. In other words, God now and then assumes various forms for His
>   lovers and reveals Himself to them as a Person. But with the rising of
>   the sun of knowledge, the blocks of ice melt. Then one doesn't feel
>   any more that God is a Person, nor does one see God's forms. What He
>   is can not be described. Who will describe Him? He who would do so
>   disappears. He cannot find his 'I' anymore.**

*The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, The Master with the Brahmo Devotees (I), October 28,1882*

Goloka is in the region of the icebergs. Those who attain Nirguna Brahman stay in the open formless ocean.

Comment: your answer trig's a story about SatCitAnanda.it goes like this - There is a wonderful Japanese Lantern Tree with a glorious veil of a multitude of red lantern blossoms with golden stamens, this is my Being my Sat. I as Consciousness enter the golden stamen, the red petals, its veins and tributaries, 
its stems,  its twig's, its branches, its trunk, its roots, the earth and beyond into the conscious limitless realm of emptiness known as Nirguna Brahaman, this is my Consciousness my Cit and   finally  I am emersed in the Golden realm of Bliss known as Ananda my home.